# Invalid type: JSON2Apex.parse

Tags: apex, json

I am trying to parse my JSON string into salesforce so i can manipulate it and use the information to create some objects. Issue is when I try to  use the parse function it isn't mapping and I am getting the error:

> Invalid type: JSON2Dir.parse

Any ideas ? As everything I have read this is how it is implemented.

**JSON2Dir class**

```
public class JSON2Dir{
    public String etag; 
    public Integer items_per_page;  
    public Integer active_count;    
    public Integer inactive_count;  
    public Integer total_results;   
    public cls_items[] items;
    public cls_links links;
    public Integer start_index; 
    public String kind; 
    public Integer resigned_count;  
    class cls_items {
        public String nationality;  //British
        public cls_address address;
        public String name; //FAIRHURST, Russell William
        public String appointed_on; //2004-01-30
        public String officer_role; //secretary
        public cls_links links;
    }
    class cls_address {
        public String postal_code;  //LU5 5XE
        public String locality; //Dunstable
        public String address_line_1;   //Whitbread Court Houghton Hall
        public String address_line_2;   //Business Park Porz Avenue
        public String region;   //Bedfordshire
    }
    class cls_links {
        public String self; 
    }
    class cls_officer {
        public String appointments; 
    }
    public static JSON2Dir parse(String json){
        return (JSON2Dir) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Dir.class);
    }
```

}

**PullDirectors class**

```
global with sharing class PullDirectors {

   webservice static String getDirectors(String regNumber) {
    //test
      //C_House CH = new C_House();
      C_House.CompaniesHouseCalloutsResponse CHresp = new C_House.CompaniesHouseCalloutsResponse();
      C_House.CompaniesHouseCalloutsRequest CHreq = new C_House.CompaniesHouseCalloutsRequest();
      C_House.CompaniesHouse.OfficerList CH = new C_House.CompaniesHouse.OfficerList();
      // On success, return a message to the calling program.
      String json;
      json = CHreq.getRequestOfficersList(regNumber);
      JSON2Dir Dir = new JSON2Dir.parse(json); 

      System.debug('CH : ' + test);
      return test;
   }

}
```

Also Example JSON response:

```
{"start_index":0,"resigned_count":28,"inactive_count":0,"etag":"af3645083fb8bb104fc42d58e01c9f38be1dcf4c","links":{"self":"/company/01270695/officers"},"items":[{"officer_role":"secretary","appointed_on":"2004-01-30","name":"FAIRHURST, Russell William","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/Dl5W8mieRiNMJgutiePVDiiQrs0/appointments"}},"nationality":"British","address":{"postal_code":"LU5 5XE","locality":"Dunstable","address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue","region":"Bedfordshire"}},{"nationality":"British","name":"LOWRY, Daren Clive","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/7wlTqN4bUrGsviZG7xv5NBTa6ls/appointments"}},"appointed_on":"2004-01-30","officer_role":"secretary","address":{"locality":"Dunstable","postal_code":"LU5 5XE","address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue","address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","region":"Bedfordshire"}},{"occupation":"Director","address":{"address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue","address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","locality":"Dunstable","postal_code":"LU5 5XE","region":"Bedfordshire"},"appointed_on":"2013-03-18","date_of_birth":{"month":8,"year":1970},"officer_role":"director","name":"COTTA, Jason","nationality":"British","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/9QLiPPZgMiOemY2-zQT95lcUFeM/appointments"}},"country_of_residence":"United Kingdom"},{"address":{"address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue","address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","region":"Bedfordshire","postal_code":"LU5 5XE","locality":"Dunstable"},"occupation":"Finance Director","appointed_on":"2015-04-16","date_of_birth":{"month":7,"year":1978},"country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","nationality":"British","name":"HIGHFIELD, Sarah Louise","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/MPqE4JO8KUCg2sFtEUFBVRM_-Jo/appointments"}},"officer_role":"director"},{"occupation":"Managing Director","address":{"region":"Bedfordshire","locality":"Dunstable","postal_code":"LU5 5XE","address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue","address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall"},"appointed_on":"2016-06-20","date_of_birth":{"year":1971,"month":5},"officer_role":"director","country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","name":"PAUL, Dominic James","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/3Wi2Er1pbxypGoi1-_d_C-QfnrY/appointments"}},"nationality":"British"},{"occupation":"Group Hr Director Costa","address":{"region":"Bedfordshire","postal_code":"LU5 5XE","address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue","locality":"Dunstable","address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall"},"appointed_on":"2016-10-13","date_of_birth":{"year":1972,"month":3},"officer_role":"director","country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","nationality":"British","name":"SELJEFLOT, Katherine Joanna","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/G_ZupARFe09AWuuqRZ1gYfqdR4o/appointments"}}},{"officer_role":"secretary","appointed_on":"1997-05-27","name":"BUXTON SMITH, Maria Rita","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/Z9uebB15Cy64dVLYqqbCJh87mSE/appointments"}},"resigned_on":"2002-09-25","address":{"region":"Bucks","locality":"Newport Pagnell","postal_code":"MK16 8RH","address_line_1":"83 Wordsworth Avenue"}},{"links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/iltSHba44-20R1ZekmECvGC2O2A/appointments"}},"name":"COSTA, Yolanda","officer_role":"secretary","address":{"region":"Surrey","locality":"Purley","postal_code":"CR8 3LJ","address_line_1":"The Copse 9 Rose Walk"},"resigned_on":"1995-10-01"},{"resigned_on":"1995-10-09","address":{"postal_code":"W1Y 2AD","locality":"London","address_line_1":"78 Brook Street"},"appointed_on":"1995-10-01","officer_role":"secretary","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/iHLK-qzk42T_JiXxz-ZAzoflteQ/appointments"}},"name":"D & H B SECRETARIAL SERVICES LIMITED"},{"appointed_on":"1995-10-09","officer_role":"secretary","name":"FENTON, Nicola Jane","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/R38gj8kZIH2Rajt9GgdbrMmyUK8/appointments"}},"resigned_on":"1997-05-27","address":{"locality":"Hampstead","postal_code":"NW3 1ND","region":"London","address_line_1":"Flat 1","address_line_2":"56 Rosslyn Hill"}},{"resigned_on":"2004-01-30","address":{"address_line_1":"85 Silverdale Road","postal_code":"RG6 7NF","locality":"Reading","region":"Berkshire","address_line_2":"Earley"},"appointed_on":"2002-09-25","officer_role":"secretary","name":"THORPE, Elizabeth Anne","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/0NWwYUDiU7C83qk0fzbXvlFZ0EQ/appointments"}}},{"name":"BENNETT, Joanna Mary","nationality":"British","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/3dqCBv6IQwSc5vJ3Q-oa9gmgF9I/appointments"}},"country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","officer_role":"director","date_of_birth":{"year":1959,"month":1},"resigned_on":"2016-10-13","appointed_on":"2014-02-13","address":{"locality":"Dunstable","postal_code":"LU5 5XE","address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue","region":"Bedfordshire"},"occupation":"Group Hr Director Costa"},{"date_of_birth":{"month":3,"year":1967},"resigned_on":"2017-01-31","nationality":"British","name":"BENTLEY, Clive","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/25a4yRmVgnRPa6xxSjgcBlJ61zc/appointments"}},"officer_role":"director","address":{"address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","region":"Bedfordshire","postal_code":"LU5 5XE","address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue","locality":"Dunstable"},"occupation":"Property Director","appointed_on":"2009-01-26"},{"date_of_birth":{"year":1955,"month":3},"resigned_on":"1997-02-24","country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","nationality":"British","name":"CLEWLEY, Robert Richard","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/PuZMrfk8eLuLEuj0vHKGMb5FJHw/appointments"}},"officer_role":"director","address":{"address_line_2":"Tonbridge Road","address_line_1":"Sunfield House","region":"Kent","locality":"Ightham","postal_code":"TN15 9AR"},"occupation":"Executive","appointed_on":"1995-10-09"},{"nationality":"Italian","name":"COSTA, Sergio Giorgio","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/jOAO2Ih0DUi9H-uZSGcpjZevcN4/appointments"}},"officer_role":"director","date_of_birth":{"year":1949,"month":4},"resigned_on":"1995-10-09","address":{"postal_code":"MC 98000","locality":"Monte Carlo","country":"Monaco","address_line_1":"1254 Palais De La Scala","address_line_2":"1 Avenue Henry Dunant"},"occupation":"Director"},{"address":{"region":"Surrey","postal_code":"CR8 3LJ","locality":"Purley","address_line_1":"The Copse 9 Rose Walk"},"occupation":"Director","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/iltSHba44-20R1ZekmECvGC2O2A/appointments"}},"name":"COSTA, Yolanda","nationality":"Italian","officer_role":"director","date_of_birth":{"year":1948,"month":11},"resigned_on":"1995-10-01"},{"address":{"address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue","address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","postal_code":"LU5 5XE","locality":"Dunstable","region":"Bedfordshire"},"occupation":"Managing Director","appointed_on":"2006-06-13","date_of_birth":{"month":12,"year":1956},"resigned_on":"2012-07-19","country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","nationality":"British","name":"DERKACH, John","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/LesY2peG92IexlgcW7RKACsG-z0/appointments"}},"officer_role":"director"},{"date_of_birth":{"year":1955,"month":8},"resigned_on":"2001-05-04","country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","nationality":"British","name":"DOWELL, Michael Charles Weston","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/0QQu4mCL5i4pi3X4o-m1ecj4ozA/appointments"}},"officer_role":"director","address":{"postal_code":"CM22 7HQ","region":"Hertfordshire","country":"England","address_line_1":"High Street","address_line_2":"Hatfield Broad Oak","locality":"Bishops Stortford","premises":"Post House"},"occupation":"Managing Director","appointed_on":"1996-12-01"},{"appointed_on":"2001-04-02","occupation":"Solicitor","address":{"locality":"London","address_line_2":"Muswell Hill","postal_code":"N10 2RD","address_line_1":"37 Windermere Road"},"officer_role":"director","nationality":"British","name":"FAIRHURST, Russell William","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/Dl5W8mieRiNMJgutiePVDiiQrs0/appointments"}},"country_of_residence":"England","resigned_on":"2001-04-18","date_of_birth":{"month":9,"year":1963}},{"appointed_on":"2003-10-28","address":{"address_line_2":"Ealing","address_line_1":"16 Lindfield Road","locality":"London","postal_code":"W5 1QR"},"occupation":"Accountant","nationality":"British","name":"FOWLER, James Dominic","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/rdGN4IH4fKWNIp1YC8_7O7K1GSw/appointments"}},"officer_role":"director","date_of_birth":{"month":7,"year":1967},"resigned_on":"2004-09-20"},{"country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/DzVPRbue2HbbNfFPYLzCtdeoXC0/appointments"}},"name":"HARDY, Helen","nationality":"British","officer_role":"director","date_of_birth":{"year":1961,"month":3},"resigned_on":"2014-02-13","appointed_on":"2010-03-08","address":{"address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue","locality":"Dunstable","postal_code":"LU5 5XE","region":"Bedfordshire"},"occupation":"Director"},{"officer_role":"director","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/aW6-l8iXGFIzTp4XjkqhbxaJRJY/appointments"}},"name":"JOHNSON, Adrian James","nationality":"British","resigned_on":"2013-01-25","date_of_birth":{"year":1964,"month":2},"appointed_on":"2008-06-27","occupation":"Chief Operating Officer","address":{"region":"Bedfordshire","address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue","address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","locality":"Dunstable","postal_code":"LU5 5XE"}},{"resigned_on":"1999-02-18","date_of_birth":{"month":3,"year":1956},"officer_role":"director","name":"JOHNSON, Michael Andrew","nationality":"British","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/_F4DnVVc7aX5UGuP6Cn2kLPi6SE/appointments"}},"country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","occupation":"Managing Director Chain Restau","address":{"postal_code":"SO51 0LQ","region":"Hampshire","address_line_2":"Oakley Road","locality":"Mottisfont","address_line_1":"North End House"},"appointed_on":"1995-10-09"},{"occupation":"Finance Director","address":{"address_line_2":"Mill Hill","locality":"London","address_line_1":"36 Copthall Drive","postal_code":"NW7 2NB"},"appointed_on":"2000-08-10","resigned_on":"2002-02-01","date_of_birth":{"month":12,"year":1957},"officer_role":"director","country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","name":"MANSIGANI, Mohan","nationality":"British","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/yxpcYReKM47U-HMuQgC4P1CZNrU/appointments"}}},{"officer_role":"director","country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","name":"MARSHALL, Andrew John","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/omTiawqphNVwyGVpuv2BgRVEaQE/appointments"}},"nationality":"British","resigned_on":"2015-06-15","date_of_birth":{"year":1960,"month":12},"appointed_on":"2010-03-08","occupation":"Director","address":{"address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue","address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","locality":"Dunstable","postal_code":"LU5 5XE","region":"Bedfordshire"}},{"occupation":"Director","address":{"postal_code":"LU5 5XE","locality":"Dunstable","region":"Bedfordshire","address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue"},"appointed_on":"2015-04-16","resigned_on":"2017-04-30","date_of_birth":{"year":1977,"month":4},"officer_role":"director","country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/_vAHtXSZUbR7t_236JZme4UX9wU/appointments"}},"name":"MCGOWAN, Murray Henry","nationality":"British"},{"appointed_on":"2002-01-01","address":{"address_line_1":"Scotts Cottage","address_line_2":"Scots Lane","locality":"Adstock","postal_code":"MK18 2HX","region":"Buckinghamshire"},"occupation":"Accountant","name":"PHILLIPS, Mark Randall","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/64LGut81iaUXAJERs09m2-rYBYE/appointments"}},"nationality":"British","country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","officer_role":"director","date_of_birth":{"year":1957,"month":11},"resigned_on":"2006-06-30"},{"address":{"postal_code":"LU5 5XE","address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","region":"Bedfordshire","locality":"Dunstable","address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue"},"occupation":"Company Director","appointed_on":"2009-01-26","date_of_birth":{"year":1969,"month":7},"resigned_on":"2014-03-18","name":"PRICE, Matthew John","nationality":"British","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/gNE6orzOz2z-ctT_TTLkOba5BB0/appointments"}},"officer_role":"director"},{"country_of_residence":"England","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/EbDCCHed3gqOjZfyLs63nZTTcJw/appointments"}},"name":"ROGERS, Christopher Charles Bevan","nationality":"British","officer_role":"director","date_of_birth":{"month":4,"year":1960},"resigned_on":"2016-06-20","appointed_on":"2012-07-06","address":{"address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","postal_code":"LU5 5XE","region":"Bedfordshire","locality":"Dunstable","address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue"},"occupation":"Director"},{"officer_role":"director","nationality":"British","name":"SIMPSON, Richard Barry","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/CYAhSoQ6VG1P1fhYV6m0hArmwPA/appointments"}},"country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","resigned_on":"2000-08-10","date_of_birth":{"year":1948,"month":12},"appointed_on":"1995-10-09","occupation":"Finance Director","address":{"region":"Northamptonshire","locality":"Northampton","address_line_2":"53 Dallington Road","postal_code":"NN5 7BW","address_line_1":"Astra House"}},{"appointed_on":"2010-03-08","occupation":"Director","address":{"postal_code":"LU5 5XE","address_line_2":"Business Park Porz Avenue","address_line_1":"Whitbread Court Houghton Hall","locality":"Dunstable","region":"Bedfordshire"},"officer_role":"director","country_of_residence":"England","name":"SLATER, Kenneth James","nationality":"British","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/70y_lTDL2max6QWtrYkJONZTeHA/appointments"}},"resigned_on":"2015-11-19","date_of_birth":{"month":7,"year":1969}},{"appointed_on":"2001-07-01","occupation":"Company Director","address":{"region":"Hertfordshire","postal_code":"HP4 2RQ","address_line_2":"Frithsden Copse Potten End","locality":"Berkhamsted","address_line_1":"Gade House"},"officer_role":"director","nationality":"British","name":"TYE, Michael Edward","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/k05BCLqlBlstvitdXJCYd9ZIRnQ/appointments"}},"country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","resigned_on":"2003-10-28","date_of_birth":{"month":12,"year":1953}},{"appointed_on":"2004-09-20","occupation":"Director","address":{"postal_code":"E1W 3SJ","address_line_1":"61 Wapping Wall","premises":"36 Merchant Court","locality":"London"},"officer_role":"director","country_of_residence":"United Kingdom","name":"WOODHOUSE, Loraine","nationality":"British","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/CUH3MULCwb4jfkAyqgEkCyPB2HU/appointments"}},"resigned_on":"2008-06-27","date_of_birth":{"year":1968,"month":12}},{"date_of_birth":{"year":1957,"month":6},"resigned_on":"2001-11-30","links":{"officer":{"appointments":"/officers/otps14yX4edHMXJVYbcZlCbXMhw/appointments"}},"name":"WRIGHT, Nicholas David","nationality":"British","officer_role":"director","address":{"address_line_1":"Kilby House","address_line_2":"Danesbury Park Road","locality":"Welwyn Garden City","postal_code":"AL6 9SF","region":"Herts"},"occupation":"Finance Director","appointed_on":"2001-07-30"}],"kind":"officer-list","items_per_page":35,"total_results":34,"active_count":6}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to call static method of the class, you need to use `ClassName.staticMethodName`.
keyword `new` means, creating new instance of class.
In this example you have static method `parse` of `JSON2Dir` class.
So you need to  remove `new` word.

`JSON2Dir Dir = JSON2Dir.parse(json);`

Comment: You should explain why "new" shouldn't be used.